# "Your browser sent an invalid request" Error in Haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I am getting **400 Bad request** - **Your browser sent an invalid request.** for the request. The request size is 28KB.

```
< HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
<
<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>
```

I have following configurations in my haproxy.conf

```
maxconn 100000 
tune.bufsize 32768
tune.maxrewrite 1024
```

What is the right settings to solve 400 Bad request error.

Comment: Your browser (or well, your HTTP client) has send a request with invalid HTTP syntax. This is something the client has to fix in general (hence the 400 status code: 4xx errors mean "client error" while 5xx errors denote server errors). HAProxy's HTTP parser also ensures valid syntax of the request and rejects invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

based on this link: https://www.geekersdigest.com/max-http-request-header-size-server-comparison/

looks like the request header is too big. It should be smaller than 16K, which is the default header size limit